# No of ways to walk M steps in a grid

Tags: algorithm, math

You are situated in an grid at position x,y. The dimensions of the row is dx,dy. In one step, you can walk one step ahead or behind in the row or the column. In how many ways can you take M steps such that you do not leave the grid at any point ?
You can visit the same position more than once.
You leave the grid if you for any x,y either x,y <= 0 or x,y > dx,dy.
1 <= M <= 300
1 <= x,y <= dx,dy <= 100

Input:
M
x y
dx dy

Output:
no of ways

Example:
Input:
1
6 6
12 12

Output:
4

Example:
Input:
2
6 6
12 12

Output:
16
If you are at position 6,6 then you can walk to (6,5),(6,7),(5,6),(7,6).

I am stuck at how to use Pascal's Triangle to solve it.Is that the correct approach? I have already tried brute force but its too slow.

```
C[i][j], Pascal Triangle
C[i][j] = C[i - 1][j - 1] + C[i - 1][j]

T[startpos][stp]
T[pos][stp] = T[pos + 1][stp - 1] + T[pos - 1][stp - 1]
```

Comment: SO doesn't work like that. You post your code and ask about a problem with it, or you ask specific questions about different approaches to your problem. You don't post a puzzle and wait for the answers to roll in.

Comment: You do not specify whether one may visit the same position more than once. Are you looking for a solution which allows or prohibits this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be an O(n^3) dynamic programming solution:

Prepare a 3D array:

```
int Z[dx][dy][M]
```

Where Z[i][j][n] holds the number of paths that start from position (i,j) and last n moves.

The base case is Z[i][j][0] = 1 for all i, j

The recursive case is Z[i][j][n+1] = Z[i-1][j][n] + Z[i+1][j][n] + Z[i][j-1][n] + Z[i][j+1][n] (only include terms in the sumation that are on the map)

Once the array is filled out return Z[x][y][M]

To save space you can discard each 2D array for n after it is used.

Comment: I need a faster solution than O(n^3)

Comment: With the constraints given 300 x 100 x 100, this will only take a few milliseconds.  I think this is what they are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve 1d problem with the formula you provided.

Let `H[pos][step]` be number of ways to move horizontal using given number of steps.
And `V[pos][step]` be number of ways to move vertical sing given number of steps.

You can iterate number of steps that will be made horizontal `i = 0..M`
Number of ways to move so is `H[x][i]*V[y][M-i]*C[M][i]`, where C is binomial coefficient.

You can build H and V in `O(max(dx,dy)*M)` and do second step in `O(M)`.

**EDIT:** *Clarification on H and V.* Supppose that you have line, that have d cells: 1,2,...,d. You're standing at cell number pos then `T[pos][step] = T[pos-1][step-1] + T[pos+1][step-1]`, as you can move either forward or backward.

Base cases are `T[0][step] = 0`, `T[d+1][step] = 0`, `T[pos][0] = 1`.

We build H assuming `d = dx` and V assuming `d = dy`.

**EDIT 2:** Basically, the *idea* of algorithm is since we move in one of 2 dimensions and check is also based on each dimension independently, we can split 2d problem in 2 1d problems.

Comment: does this count all possible interleavings of horizontal and vertical moves?

Comment: @kilotaras Can you explain H & V in more detail

Comment: @kilotaras M=2 dx=1 dy=12 x = 1 y = 6. V[6][2]*C[2][0]+V[6][1]*C[2][1]+V[6][0]*C[2][2] = (4*1)+(2*2)+(1*1)??

Comment: @user1301541 V[6][2]*H[1][0]*C[2][0]+V[6][1]*H[1][1]*C[2][1]+V[6][0]*H[1][2]*C[2][2] = (4*1*1)+(2*0*2)+(1*0*1) = 4

Comment: can you  please tell me how do we solve for a n dimensional whose dimension is known at run time

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Java solution I've built for the original [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/grid-walking) problem. For big grids runs forever. Probably some smart math is needed.

```
long compute(int N, int M, int[] positions, int[] dimensions) {
    if (M == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (positions[i] < dimensions[i]) {
            positions[i]++;
            sum += compute(N, M - 1, positions, dimensions);
            positions[i]--;
        }
        if (positions[i] > 1) {
            positions[i]--;
            sum += compute(N, M - 1, positions, dimensions);
            positions[i]++;
        }
    }
    return sum % 1000000007;
}
```